# Blazor WASM .NET 5 input time do not show correctly

Tags: c#, datetime, input, blazor-webassembly

After upgrading Blazor WASM app from .NET core 3.1 to 5 I no longer get a correct view of my time input:

```
<input type="time" @bind="myTime" @bind:format=@myTimeFormat />
@code{
    DateTime myTime = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
    string myTimeFormat = "HH:mm:ss"; 
}
```

used to result in a "HH:mm:ss" view of the time.

Now all I get is
"--:--"

(same in Chrome/Edge/Firefox)

Chrome console prints the following:

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 The specified value "12.52.58" does not
> conform to the required format.  The format is "HH:mm", "HH:mm:ss" or
> "HH:mm:ss.SSS" where HH is 00-23, mm is 00-59, ss is 00-59, and SSS is
> 000-999.

I guess there is something in the way the time value is passed around...
Does anyone know howto get around this (hopefully without using manual strings /parsing forth and back that I see as the only option here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add ' around :, like so:

```
string myTimeFormat = "HH':'mm':'ss";
```

For more info see [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30507#issuecomment-805779832).